# Show that $(\aleph)^{\aleph_0} < (\aleph_0)^{\aleph} $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Couldn't find answers like that, so I would ask.

At first, let's note that ${\aleph}=c $ in our case. Now, we need to show that:
$$(\aleph)^{\aleph_0} < (\aleph_0)^{\aleph} $$

For the left part of this inequality, we know that $\aleph^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\aleph_0}=\aleph$.

But for the right part, can we assume that ${\aleph_0}^{\aleph}={\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0}⋅{\aleph_0}^{\aleph}={\aleph}⋅{\aleph_0}^{\aleph}$,

thus making it greater than $\aleph^{\aleph_0}$?

Thanks!

Comment: $\aleph_0^\aleph≥2^\aleph>\aleph$

Comment: May you please edit the formatting? You mean that $\aleph^{\aleph_0}$ is greater?

Comment: It is $(\aleph_0)^\aleph$ at th left most side

Comment: It makes sense now. Thank you.